# InfoPath Forms and autoprinting

Tags: infopath

I am new to InfoPath Forms and have created my form but trying to add a link/button where user can select and it will autoprint. Is this an option??

Answer (score 1):

Because printing is an action that takes place on a client machine, not in the browser, there is not an out of the box option for this. In order to create a "button" for this, you would have to custom code it and make sure you sign it and publish it with full trust. The best option is to create a button that takes the user to a print view where it is a simple form that will look ok to print on a black and white printer and then in the top of the page, tell them to press ctrl+p or use the browser print button.

Answer (score 0):

Open your form in Design Mode, then go into Tools --> Form Options --> Browser.  Check the option to display "Print View".  This will give your users an option to print, although they will need to do it from the browser.

If that's not what you were looking for, you can also do what Lori suggested.

Access the "Views" from the Design Task sidebar.  Look towards the bottom of the screen and there's a link to "Create Print Version for This View..."

You'll need to do a copy/paste from the main form, and then format it for printing (black and white, etc.)

Once the view is created, you can show the Print View from a button rule.